# Magento 2 / GTM Issue

Tags: magento2, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm sending data from my Magento 2 store into a GTM in order to track several aspects of the store.
Everything was working just fine and all the required data was being sent ok, but for some unknown reason the data for one specific store is no longer being sent. (this is a 4 websites each one with more than one store).

I've attached 2 pics, one shows the datalayer working and the other one simple dont work.

Can someone please help me ?

[image: Not working datalayer]
[image: Working datalayer]

Regards

Comment: did you fix this?

Comment: Hi...i've setup a "purchase" event on GTM and it started work properly

Comment: what do you mean? can you help me to setup GTM?

Comment: i'm using Weltpixel Google Tag Manger extension...it takes care of most of all the issues...on the checkout success page i've just added the purchase event

Comment: Are you talikng about their free extention?

Comment: yes..im talking about the free extension